# adobe flash player update

Tags: flash

I have been trying to figure out how to update the Adobe Flash player for Ubuntu 12.04. I am using Firefox 35 as a browser. I have tried to simply download the tar.gz file from the Adobe site, but there is no install file in the folder. I converted the tag.gz file to DEB and installed it and restarted Firefox with no luck. It seems as though it didnt install. I also read links about *ubuntu-restricted-extras* but that prompted me to remove many dependencies and other applications that I enjoy & still need. I also read about *Flashaid* which has been discontinued.

I have checked in about:config in Firefox and got the following results:

1. **Shockwave Flash**
2. File: libflashplayer.so
3. Path:/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
4. Version:11.2.202.425  State: Enabled (STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE) Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

Is there an easy way to simply just update the Flashplayer? I tried using synaptec package manger with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of flash do you need to upgrade to? Unforunately the Adobe Flash Player [about page](http://www.adobe.com/de/software/flash/about/) states that only only Chrome/ium supports versions of flash higher than 11.2.

You could have a look into installing the [Fresh Player Plugin](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-fresh-player-plugin-in-ubuntu.html). I haven't used this so I'm not 100% certain it will work for you.

As a last resort you can install Chromium from the `Ubuntu Software Center` by just searching for chromium and then installing it. Alternatively you can install [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) by downloading the .deb file then double clicking it once it has downloaded, from there it will install in the software center. I personally use Chrome and flash works absolutely fine for me.

Hope this has helped you.

Comment: I have checked in about:config in Firefox and got the following results @jkrix :

Shockwave Flash

    File: libflashplayer.so
    Path: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
    Version: 11.2.202.425
    State: Enabled (STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
    Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

Comment: on the Adobe website it says there is 11.2.202.440 availble. Not sure how to install this tar.gz file then.

Comment: Does it give the same message when going to Tools->Add ons->Plugins then to the flash player? What version does it say? What happens if you try upgrade with the link provided there?

Comment: in Tools->Add ons->Plugins is says the same version that is installed 11.2.202.425 @jkrix. ALso when I tried to install from the terminal Ubuntu said I was running latest verison =(

Comment: What happens after doing a software upgrade? `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Or perhaps even reinstalling flash `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

Do you require Firefox for browsing? Because Firefox only supports 11.2.202.440 as its latest version its probably safer to use Chrome/ium which is currently supported up to 16.0.0.296.

Comment: THe only reasonable solution was to completely abandon Firefox and install the insidious Google product. Too bad, I like open source apps, but if there is no support, then whats the point?

Comment: chromium is always crashing now, hanging pages for 30 minutes, freezing the system.

Answer (score 0):

Through [pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/) you may install the windows version of Flash. It will co-exist with your linux version so you can choose depending on your needs which to use.

Instructions on the website are very clear and easy to follow.

Pipelight also makes other plugins like Unity and Silverlight (and more) available to Linux users.